# Упростить код изменения видимости

Tags: c#, wpf, инспекция-кода

Есть форма с текстбоксами `nomer1`, `nomer2` и т.д.
При загрузке формы считывается файл в котором прописано виден бокс или нет.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\test\viseble.txt"))
{                                           
    if (reader.ReadLine() == "1 true")
    {
        nomer1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        nomer1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
    if (reader.ReadLine() == "2 true")
    {
        nomer2.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        nomer2.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

Текстбоксов много и получается очень большой кусок повторяющегося кода.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно упростить?

Comment: 1. Выражение ()?: `(expr)?Visible:Hidden` 2. Moжно использовать `((WebControl)FindControl("nomer" + i)).Visibility`

Comment: Скриншот окна покажите чтобы было понятнее о чем идет речь.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем, было найдено такое решение:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\visible.txt"))
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var box = (TextBox)FindName("textBox" + i);
        if (reader.ReadLine() == "true") { box.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; }
        else { box.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden; }
    }
}
```

Считывается любое количество строк для любого количества элементов, в зависимости от `i`.

Comment: Как может быть любое, если у Вас цикл только на 9 итераций? Ну и `FindName` вернёт `null`, если элемент не найден и получите NPE в явном виде при дальнейшем обращении к полям `box`.

Comment: Я же написал взасимости от i, сколько элементов - столько и итераций. Можно сделать i < 100 и т.д. А можно и ещё цикл сделать на считывание количества элементов, но мне и этого достаточно.

Comment: Не забывайте голосовать за ответы (стрелки слева) и выберите галочкой наиболее подходящий вариант. Можно даже свой собственный.

Answer (score 3):

Такие настройки предпочтительно хранить так:

Правый клик на названии проекта -> Properties -> Settings

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создаем нужные свойства. Scope User - настройки, которые можно изменять, Scope Application - настройки только для чтения.

```
//чтение настройки
this.textBox.Visibility = Properties.Settings.Default.ForTextBox1
            ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;

//запись настройки
Properties.Settings.Default.ForTextBox1 = false;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Answer (score 1):

Даже не меняя подхода к хранению настроек, как предложено в ответе @Bulson, код можно упростить.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\test\viseble.txt"))
{
    TextBox tbs = { nomer1, nomer2 };
    foreach (var tb in tbs) 
    {
        bool vis = reader.ReadLine() == "true";
        tb.Visibility = vis ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

Здесь я убрал необходимость иметь номер (`1` или `2`) в файле настроек, т.к. они всё равно по Вашей логике расположены последовательно, т.е. первая строка - это видимость первого бокса, вторая - второго бокса.

Comment: не, сократить нельзя, потому что _Visibility_ - это enum. Но можно заменить `true` на значения из enum, и использовать `Enum.Parse`

Comment: @Grundy ну, значит нельзя :) Я предположил, оно умеет конвертиться из `bool`, получается, ошибочно.